# Change routing separator in spine.js

Tags: routes, spine.js

How can I change the routing separator in spine.js from '#' to '#!'?
Is there a setting of any kind?

Comment: What is the reason why you would need to change that?

Comment: To make it more google friendly: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could make it work was to edit route.coffee and change

`hashStrip    = /^#*/`

to

`hashStrip    = /^#!*/`

Comment: You should turn that into a configurable option and make a pull request on github.